# Spring Security Custom Login Fallback

Tags: spring-security, ldap

Can someone please point me to some resources that can guide me on how I can implement a custom spring security authentication that first test the credentials of the found user on an ldap server first if the field for the ldap username exists for that user, and failing to authenticate (either because the ldap username doesn't exist or the password given doesn't authenticate the username on the server) there would attempt to authenticate against the local password kept hashed in the local database for the user.

Thank you.

Comment: You can read the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-ldap) and try the [sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/ldap) from Spring Security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there aren't too many good answers to that specific question available.

While I have not stood up a full working LDAP example, there should be a good start to that part in the [ldap sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/ldap) that @Marcus linked in the comments. Having said that, you can easily register two authentication providers in the order you want, with the default `DaoAuthenticationProvider` being second:

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        return http
            .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .formLogin(withDefaults())
            .authenticationProvider(ldapAuthenticationProvider())
            .authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider())
            .build();
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider ldapAuthenticationProvider() {
        LdapContextSource contextSource = null; // TODO See sample for example
        return new LdapAuthenticationProvider(new BindAuthenticator(contextSource));
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails userDetails = User.builder()
            .username("user")
            .password("{noop}password")
            .roles("USER")
            .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(userDetails);
    }

}
```

You will obviously want to provide your own user details which uses a database instead of in-memory. The [username-password sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/authentication/username-password/user-details-service/custom-user) would get you started with that, and you can replace the `MapCustomUserRepository` in that example with e.g. a spring data `@Repository`.